# should subject have collection of observers

Tags: design-patterns, observer-pattern

In the Observer Pattern, should a `Subject` have a collection of `Observer`s even though I need only one `Observer`? Every diagram or application I see using Observer Pattern has many `Observer`s. Is it called Observer Pattern if it has only one `Observer`?

Answer (score 2):

From the GoF book page 295,

> Any number of Observer objects may observe a subject.

This is why you see a collection of Observers in every example. A subject supports more than one; however, it is not required to have more than one. "*Any number*" includes the number 1.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, perfectly okay. Like in MVC, an object in presentation / application facade layer may be the only object that listens to a particular domain object.

Remember the specification of Subject and Observer - there is no mention of a collection there. Observer has an update() method and Subject has a register() method. That's it! Collection is an implementation detail. :)